# Alamofire is going in failure block on API Call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In api calling it goes to success block every time but sometimes with same request it returns failure block. everything is working fine but when i try to request multiple time then it's going in failure block.  here is code:

```
class func makeRequest(with url: String, method: HTTPMethod , success: @escaping ( response: Any) -> Void, failure: @escaping ( error: String) -> Void) {


    Alamofire.request(url, method: method,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch (response.result) {
        case .success(let value):
            if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted) {
                print("Response: \n",String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "nil")
            }
            success(value)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            failure("Failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Error Description:

```
2018-03-13 13:33:44.581060+0530 ***** TIC Read Status [17:0x6000001681c0]: 1:54
2018-03-13 13:33:44.584038+0530 ***** Task <E773098C-875E-49DF-B2EA-F14F8F35C217>.<9> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
2018-03-13 13:33:44.584421+0530****** Task <E773098C-875E-49DF-B2EA-F14F8F35C217>.<9> finished with error - code: -1005
Request failed with error: The network connection was lost.
The network connection was lost.
```

but there is no connection issue. success block is executed if i send request one after one on time interval. problem occurs only when sending same request multiple time at same time.

Comment: That seems to be an issue with the API and not with the code.

Comment: @joelfischerr it is going to success block every time if i send request on some time interval. But only when i send same request multiple times simultaneously that time it goes to failure block

Comment: can you show error description...

Comment: it depends on your API, if its running locally with little resources, or if its rate limited you may get this issue. The API could be under heavy load or the requests your making could be putting it under strain. seems more of a concurrency/capacity issue rather than the Swift code

Comment: @junaidUmer  i added error description in question.

Comment: @Scriptable then what will be possible solution for handling concurrent request?

Comment: As i said previously, that depends on your API which you haven't provided any information about so I cannot answer that. This is no longer a Swift question, update your question with information about your API